# Many to Many relationship JPA, EJB and new table in db

Tags: jpa, entity, eclipselink, ejb-3.1, javadb

i'm working on javaEE (7) Entreprise application with EJB, JPA and JSF2.2 (NetBeans 8.0.2 and GF 4.1)
this is my design in JavaDB : 2 tables with a Many to Many relationship so a new table "Avoir" is generated.

a "Document" has several "Critere" and "Critere" can belong to several "Document".
my problem is when i generate Entities Classes from Databases with Eclipselink 2.1, i have only a "Document" and "Critere" classes, but no "Avoir" class.

my question is, how can i add row in "Avoir" table ?

NB : this the code of my 2 classes

Critere code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRITERE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Critere.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Critere c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Critere.findByIdcritere", query = "SELECT c FROM Critere c WHERE c.idcritere = :idcritere"),
// Others Query …
public class Critere implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "IDCRITERE")
// Other columns …
@JoinTable(name = "AVOIR", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDCRITERE", referencedColumnName = "IDCRITERE")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDDOC", referencedColumnName = "IDDOC")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Document> documentCollection;
// Other mappings ...
```

and Document code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Document.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Document d"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Document.findByIddoc", query = "SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.iddoc = :iddoc"),
// Other Query …    
public class Document implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "IDDOC")
private Integer iddoc;
// Other columns …

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "documentCollection")
private Collection<Critere> critereCollection;
// Other mappings …
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that. `@ManyToMany` is implemented using a join table (`AVOIR` in your case), and the persistence provider takes care of wiring it all up in the database. Your responsibility is only to maintain both sides of the relationship, meaning if you add one `Critere` to a `Document`, be sure that `Document` also has that `Critere` in the list.

`@JoinTable` defines the table which is used for relationship, `joinColumns` attribute defines the column which is a foreign key to source table (`CRITERE`) and `inverseJoinColumns` attribute defines the column which is a foreign key to target table (`DOCUMENT`).

```
Document doc = em.find(Document.class, 1L);
Critere cit = em.find(Critere .class, 1L);
// you just need to maintain both sides of the relationship
doc.getCritereCollection().add(crit);
crit.getDocumentCollection().add(doc);
em.merge(doc); // not really needed because these are attached entities (if executed inside of transaction)
```

This will add a row in `AVOIR` table, with value `1` in both columns.

Comment: thank you @Predrag Maric for your answer, i understand better now.

but I remain worried about how to view documents with their criteria. i dont have any column in Document table or Document class.

when i want to add a new Document, i should add a Criteria_ID, how can i do that in jsf page without any attribute in my Document Class ?

Comment: Join table is used instead of join columns, so there is no need for `criteria_id` or similar. If you want to know how ORM puts it all together, turn on SQL logging, and see the generated SQL when you save new or select existing documents.

Comment: what i dont understand it's how can i specify in my "managed bean" code and jsf which "Critere" it's for this "Document" ?

Comment: I've added code example, hopefully it will clear things up for you (I think you might be overthinking this one).

Comment: amazing example dude, i will try this in the afternoon and come back to you, i think it's clear now

Comment: works perfectly, thank you @Predrag Maric.
your example helped me to solve other problems